# Take Cookie value insert into php string

Tags: php, html, cookies

I'm making a simple page for our home server for keeping track of in game currency..
My problem was when this line
    $Tlab = number_format($Tlae - $TlSL + $TlSW , 2, '.', '');

is done, it does work and it spits out the

```
fclose ($fp);
echo ("[Prv Amount is [$Tlae]  ");
echo ("[Win Amount is [$TlSW]  ");
echo ("[Loss is [$TlSL]  ");
echo ("[Total [$Tlab]  ");
```

Odd thing is.. the TLab will write its sum value to a cookie, however when it is put into the url to insert into the next page, the value is empty

```
<A HREF="curncy.php?Tlab=<?php echo $_REQUEST["Tlab"]; ?>"> [Next Round]</A><br />
```

Did I do something wrong, because any other values used will get passed on??
Or as the cookie does store the $Tlab value [when I do an echo in the next page it does show correctly] how do I take that value from the cookie and give it a workable value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

On previeous page: `setcookie('Tlab', $Tlab);`

On next page: `$_COOKIE['Tlab'];`

**Option 2:**

On previous page:
`<A HREF="curncy.php?Tlab=<?php echo $Tlab; ?>">`

On next page:
`$_REQUEST["Tlab"];` or `$_GET["Tlab"];`

You should read more on [cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) and [http requests](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: I looked over a bing search for the cookie solution but it all went to simple background colors etc... I started to update myself on the changes and doing some catch up with http, I had to set it aside to do some paying work, batch scripting several smb server/client routines and set a few other unpleasant tasks lol.. I did go back to the pages in question and what youi have in Opt 2 'request' line is there... i'll try the get.. I do thank you for saving me a few headaches ;-)

Comment: Not a problem at all, glad to be of help. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Also have a look at the formatting tutorials at SO [meta]